# Nohup doesn't work with my Windows syntax from WSL2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nohup

I am running Tiddlywiki as portable from OneDrive, following [this](https://techlifeweb.com/tiddlywiki/tw5tribalknowledge/static/Getting%2520Started%2520with%2520Node.js%2520on%2520Windows.html) tutorial.

I am running this from WSL2:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/mobil/OneDrive/node && nohup cmd.exe /c tiddlywiki.cmd mynewwiki --listen
```

In my previous Linux install I only needed to run this, but this doesn't work for my new Linux install for some reason:

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/mobil/OneDrive/node && nohup tiddlywiki mynewwiki --listen
```

Tiddlywiki starts but nohup doesn't work properly with my new command (even though I am getting the "nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’", if I close the terminal, the process stops.
Why?

If I am in the node folder this will give me the Tiddlywiki version:

```
./node.exe node_modules/tiddlywiki/tiddlywiki.js --version

lantos@DESKTOP-259UMQ1:~$ ls -l /mnt/c/Users/mobil/OneDrive/node
total 61088
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos    56507 Oct  9 20:30 CHANGELOG.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos    88859 Oct  9 20:30 LICENSE
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos    35474 Oct  9 20:30 README.md
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      334 Oct  9 20:30 corepack
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      218 Oct  9 20:30 corepack.cmd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos     3033 Oct  9 20:30 install_tools.bat
drwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      512 Jan  9 17:45 mynewwiki
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos 62283384 Oct  9 20:30 node.exe
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos    10630 Oct  9 20:30 node_etw_provider.man
drwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      512 Jan  9 17:45 node_modules
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      702 Oct  9 20:30 nodevars.bat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos    39771 Jan 18 13:35 nohup.out
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos     1365 Oct  9 20:30 npm
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      483 Oct  9 20:30 npm.cmd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos     1567 Oct  9 20:30 npx
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      539 Oct  9 20:30 npx.cmd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      336 Oct  9 20:37 tiddlywiki
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      339 Oct  9 20:37 tiddlywiki.cmd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 lantos lantos      861 Oct  9 20:37 tiddlywiki.ps1
lantos@DESKTOP-259UMQ1:~$ cat /mnt/c/Users/mobil/OneDrive/node/tiddlywiki.cmd
@ECHO off
GOTO start
:find_dp0
SET dp0=%~dp0
EXIT /b
:start
SETLOCAL
CALL :find_dp0

IF EXIST "%dp0%\node.exe" (
  SET "_prog=%dp0%\node.exe"
) ELSE (
  SET "_prog=node"
  SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
)

endLocal & goto #_undefined_# 2>NUL || title %COMSPEC% & "%_prog%"  "%dp0%\node_modules\tiddlywiki\tiddlywiki.js" %*
lantos@DESKTOP-259UMQ1:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain why you want to start `cmd.exe` from WSL2. Show the contents of `tiddlywiki.cmd`. Did you install a Windows or Linux version of `tiddlywiki `?

Comment: The question is about nohup, not about Tiddlywiki. Tiddlywiki works so it's nothing to ask about that, and it's successfully started with my command. Nohup also seems to work, since it's reporting nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out. But nohup doesn't work for real, because when I close the terminal window, the process stops.

Comment: This might be an issue of mixing Windows and Linux programs or of WSL in general. I suspect you might be doing something wrong, that's why I'm asking for details. The second command looks correct. In which way doesn't it work.

Comment: the second command only worked on my initial WSL2 install, on my previous Win OS, where I initially installed Tiddlywiki and Node.js into my OneDrive folder, from the WIN command prompt. Now if I install tiddlywiki again from my WSL2 terminal in the same folder, and node.js, will that be okay? Wouldn't it mess things up? But it's no need to reinstall things, since it's already runnign fine in the browser, from my OneDrive folder. The only issue is that nohup even though it starts it won't do its thing to keep the process running after the WSL2 terminal is closed.

Comment: **Please [edit] your question** to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. If you prefer to argue instead of providing the information I need to analyze the problem, then I cannot help. What exactly means "doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: My question *What exactly means "doesn't work"?* refers to the command that worked in your previous installation. What happens when you run it now?

Comment: When I run it now, I am getting "tiddlywiki: command not found" .

Comment: **Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose.** This `tiddlywiki: command not found` might indicate the real problem. Provide all information I already asked for. Maybe you installed a Linux version on the previous system and a Windows version on the current one.

Comment: Then, please explain why you think that a Linux utility `nohup` is supposed to work in combination with a Windows program `cmd.exe`. `nohup` prevents the POSIX signal SIGHUP from killing a process. It does not care about Windows specific mechanisms.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Running `nohup cmd.exe /c pause` in WSL and closing the terminal keeps the `cmd` open.

Comment: I don't think it's supposed to work, I want to find an other  syntax or find out how to run it with my old command (that does work with nohup) without reinstalling node.js or tiddlywiki in the same OneDrive folder, because that might mess things up. Node.js is not installed, it's just unpacked in the OneDrive folder. Tiddlywiki yes that is installed, but that only means that some files are copied into the OneDrive folder, so I am not supposed to install it again from Linux, just because I changed my Linux machine, right? That was the point of using OneDrive so I don't need to reinstall it.

Comment: `cd /mnt/c/Users/mobil/OneDrive/node && nohup ./tiddlywiki mynewwiki --listen` this will not start it

Comment: `./node.exe node_modules/tiddlywiki/tiddlywiki.js --version` this will give me the TiddlyWiki version if I am in the node folder. I added this in the post too.

Comment: MobilHome please STOP WRITING COMMENTS. Instead please update your question. This your fourth request to do this properly

Comment: Please show *in your question* the output of `ls -l /mnt/c/Users/mobil/OneDrive/node` and the contents of the script `/mnt/c/Users/mobil/OneDrive/node/tiddlywiki.cmd`

Comment: Why the downvotes? Provide solutions, or just leave.

Comment: I submitted the requested terminal outputs in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Found out some solutions, both executed from the node folder (/mnt/c/Users/mobil/OneDrive/node).

From Win Powershell (or from the tiddlywiki file shortcut command):

```
powershell -windowstyle hidden ./tiddlywiki.cmd mynewwiki --listen
```

From the Linux (WSL2, Ubuntu) command line:

```
nohup ./node.exe node_modules/tiddlywiki/tiddlywiki.js mynewwiki --listen &
```

(I don't think the ampersand at the end is actually necessary.)

Both tested and works.

The install was correct, I just needed more specific syntax.
This is running from Windows binaries, I created my node OneDrive folder from Windows, if I would have Linux binaries instead, then I would need other syntaxes, right?

Whichever binaries I have in my OneDrive, the syntax need to be adjusted, is that right?
I don't think I can have both binaries, or would that make sense?

Comment: Congratulations on figuring out the solution yourself. However, if you have follow-up questions, please dont't add them to your self-answer; rather, create a new question. You can still link them to this question to help establish context.